# CSR generation origin?

Tags: certificates

Platform: Windows 7 x64

Development:  .NET 4

Web Server:  HttpListener (IIS not installed, will not be installed :) )

Can Machine A generate a Certificate Signing Request for Machine B and have the cert given back by the CA (Machine C) installed on Machine B? Is there any magic that happens during CSR generation that ties it to Machine A? If Machine A CAN generate for Machine B, what is the minimum required information that would be needed to generate the CSR?

-Shane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the CSR wher ever you want. The thing is, the private key is created at the same time, and whichever server is using the signed certificate in the end also needs this private key. Usually you can export this private key on machine A and import it on machine B together with the (sigend) certificate.

The minimum information required for the CSR depends on the CA you are using.